# Spring-Redis connection not re-connecting between retries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I'm working on a Spring-Batch application, which uses a REDIS connection to populate data.

Here are some relevant dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.3.3.RELEASE'
```

RedisConnection is imported from `org.springframework.data.redis.connection`

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**
There might be a case when the RedisConnection is active when we start the application, but during the time application is running, we might loose the Redis Connection. In that case, when it enters the method below, the method will throw an error that Redis connection is lost. Hence, we retry using the @Retryable logic.
But, lets say during the second retry, the Redis Connection is re-established, we want the Retry to be able to detect that and re-connect to redis and go for the normal flow. But, **"THE REDIS-RECONNECTION IS NOT GETTING DETECTED"**

**TRIED**: I tried following https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/338 and added `lettuceConnectionFactory.validateConnection();` to the defaultRedisConnection as below but to no vain

```
    @Qualifier("defaultRedisConnection")
    @Bean
    public RedisConnection defaultRedisConnectionDockerCluster() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("redis");

        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
        lettuceConnectionFactory.validateConnection();
        lettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    }
```

Here is the class:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PopulateRedisDataService {

    @Qualifier("defaultRedisConnection")
    private final RedisConnection redisConnection;

    private RedisClientData redisClientData = new RedisClientData();

    public PopulateRedisDataService(
            @Qualifier("defaultRedisConnection") RedisConnection redisConnection,
            RedisDataUtils redisDataUtils) {
        this.redisConnection = redisConnection;
    }

    @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "3", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "20_000",
            multiplierExpression = "100_000", maxDelayExpression = "100_000"))
    public RedisClientData populateData() {
         try {
            byte[] serObj = Objects.requireNonNull(redisConnection.get("SOME_KEY".getBytes()));
            RedisClientData redisClientData = new RedisClientData();
            // Some operations to load data from Redis/serObj into redisClientData object.
        } catch (Exception e) {
             // If Redis doesn't have the key, return empty redisClientData
            redisClientData = new RedisClientData();
            log.error("Failed to get ClientRegList", e);
        }
         return redisClientData;
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception e) {
        // Some operations
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to handle this case would be much appreciated.